# Sum values of radio buttons which are not selected on left and right

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below code is giving me the sum of values of selected radio buttons. It was working fine.

But now what i want is which option is not selected on left and right then it should sum value 2 for every question. Rest should be same for selected in most preferred it is adding 3 and for least preferred it is adding 1.  I tried many option but not able to achieve my goal.

My radio buttons are in vertical position.

For example: if i choose 1st option in most preferred and 3rd option in least preferred in both questions, then 2nd option is unchecked in both the questions. Now it should give the result like this:

Networking: 4
sum_Recognition : 6
sum_KnowledgeSeeking:2

I am getting results of recognition and knowledgeseeking absolutely perfect... But i dont know how to count networking as it is unchecked option.

```js
$("input[type='radio']").change(function() {

  var sum_Networking = 0;

  var sum_Recognition = 0;

  var sum_KnowledgeSeeking = 0;






  var get_Networking = $("input[type='radio'][data-id=Networking]:checked").each(function() {
    sum_Networking += Math.ceil($(this).val());

  });


  var get_Recognition = $("input[type='radio'][data-id=Recognition]:checked").each(function() {
    sum_Recognition += Math.ceil($(this).val());
  });

  var get_KnowledgeSeeking = $("input[type='radio'][data-id=KnowledgeSeeking]:checked").each(function() {
    sum_KnowledgeSeeking += Math.ceil($(this).val());
  });


  alert("Networking: " + sum_Networking + ",\n sum_Recognition: " + sum_Recognition + ",\n sum_KnowledgeSeeking: " + sum_KnowledgeSeeking)
});
```

```css
.row-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 4px;
}

.fix-div1 {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.fix-div2 {
  width: 60%;
  text-align: center;
}

.fix-div3 {
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="multisteps-form__panel shadow rounded bg-white js-active" data-animation="slideHorz">
  <div class="bg-gray-light p-3 mb-4 pb-4 ">
    <h3 class="profile-username">
      Question 1: As you are in the arms of your dream, what motivates you the most to achieve your dream?




    </h3>
    <div class="multisteps-form__content">

      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
          <div class="row-div">

            <div class="fix-div1">
              Most Preferred

            </div>

            <div class="fix-div2">

            </div>

            <div class="fix-div3">
              Least Preferred

            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="row-div mt-2">

            <div class="fix-div1">

              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">

                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb_left_1" name="Left_1" value="3" data-id="Recognition">
                <label for="Q_1_rb_left_1" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">  </label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="fix-div2">
              Status symbol
            </div>

            <div class="fix-div3">

              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb_right_1" name="Right_1" value="1" data-id="Recognition">
                <label for="Q_1_rb_right_1" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">  </label>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="row-div mt-2">

            <div class="fix-div1">

              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">

                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb_left_2" name="Left_1" value="3" data-id="Networking">
                <label for="Q_1_rb_left_2" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">  </label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="fix-div2">
              An opportunity to be a part of various groups

            </div>

            <div class="fix-div3">

              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb_right_2" name="Right_1" value="1" data-id="Networking">
                <label for="Q_1_rb_right_2" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">  </label>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="row-div mt-2">

            <div class="fix-div1">

              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">

                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb_left_3" name="Left_1" value="3" data-id="KnowledgeSeeking">
                <label for="Q_1_rb_left_3" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">  </label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="fix-div2">
              The challenges involved in the project


            </div>

            <div class="fix-div3">

              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_1_rb_right_3" name="Right_1" value="1" data-id="KnowledgeSeeking">
                <label for="Q_1_rb_right_3" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">  </label>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>


        </div>








      </div>




    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=" p-3 pb-4 ">
    <h3 class="profile-username">
      Question 2: I would like to operate this way when working towards my dreams…




    </h3>
    <div class="multisteps-form__content">

      <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-3">
          <div class="row-div">

            <div class="fix-div1">
              Most Preferred

            </div>

            <div class="fix-div2">

            </div>

            <div class="fix-div3">
              Least Preferred

            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="row-div mt-2">

            <div class="fix-div1">

              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">

                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_2_rb_left_1" name="Left_2" value="3" @*data-id="Power" *@ data-id=Recognition>
                <label for="Q_2_rb_left_1" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">  </label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="fix-div2">
              I would be eager to be my own boss.

            </div>

            <div class="fix-div3">

              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_2_rb_right_1" name="Right_2" value="1" @*data-id="Power" *@ data-id=Recognition>
                <label for="Q_2_rb_right_1" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">  </label>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="row-div mt-2">

            <div class="fix-div1">

              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">

                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_2_rb_left_2" name="Left_2" value="3" @*data-id="SocialService" *@ data-id=Networking>
                <label for="Q_2_rb_left_2" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">  </label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="fix-div2">
              I would be eager to voluntarily support others.


            </div>

            <div class="fix-div3">

              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_2_rb_right_2" name="Right_2" value="1" @*data-id="SocialService" *@ data-id=Networking>
                <label for="Q_2_rb_right_2" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">  </label>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="row-div mt-2">

            <div class="fix-div1">

              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">

                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_2_rb_left_3" name="Left_2" value="3" @*data-id="CreativityAndInnovation" *@ data-id=KnowledgeSeeking>
                <label for="Q_2_rb_left_3" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">  </label>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="fix-div2">
              I would be eager to try out something unique.



            </div>

            <div class="fix-div3">

              <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="Q_2_rb_right_3" name="Right_2" value="1" @*data-id="CreativityAndInnovation" *@ data-id=KnowledgeSeeking>
                <label for="Q_2_rb_right_3" class="custom-control-label font-weight-normal">  </label>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>


        </div>








      </div>




    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="bg-gray-light button-row d-flex mt-4 mb-4 p-4">

    <button class="btn btn-primary ml-auto js-btn-next" type="button" title="Next">Next</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've updated my answer if you want to keep your existing code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My approach would have been to calculate question by question.

```
$(".multisteps-form__content").each(function() {
    var sum_n = 0;
    // sum checked values
    $(this).find("input[type='radio'][data-id=Networking]:checked").each(function() {
        sum_n += Math.ceil($(this).val());
    });
    // if none is checked, add 2
    sum_Networking += (sum_n == 0 ? 2 : sum_n);
    //same with recognition and the thid one

});
```

Another way to achieve this needs also a question by question check, so at the end of your code that actually works for checked questions, you can do :

```
$(".multisteps-form__content").each(function() {
    if($(this).find("input[type='radio'][data-id=Networking]:checked").length==0) sum_Networking += 2;
    //same with recognition and the thid one

});
```

Comment: what if in any question data_id=Networking not found.. Still it will sum 2 in the value... which i dont want

Comment: Wasn't clear in your OP that you have some questions without networking question. But then you just have to change by *if($(this).find("input[type='radio'][data-id=Networking]:checked").length==0 && $(this).find("input[type='radio'][data-id=Networking]").length>0)*